# Has the token length and formatting been updated recently with the YouTube data api?

Tags: oauth, youtube-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api

I left an inquiry using Google Translate.
Please understand even if you are not familiar with English.

We found a change related to the access_token value while accessing the YouTube API and sent an inquiry.

I used the 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth' YouTube API.

I get data with return response 'access_token'.

However, recent token data length changes
Previously 165 characters, now 220 characters

I would like to know if there are any changes in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

Google has not documented any format or length for its tokens.   As its not documented this is most likely due to the fact that it can change when ever they change their system.

The access token should work no matter what the length of it.

[Oauth2 size](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#size)

[image]

Comment: Late, but this answer was really helpful.
Thank you so much for leaving so quickly.